# Areca Palm black spots yellow leaves

Tags: areca-palm

Areca Palm stems have black spots that look to be spreading upward. Leaves turning yellow then brown drying out. Watering once a week 16 oz of water. What do I need to do? Also tried adding some potassium to the soil.

Comment: Hi Kim. Could you please include a picture since it paints 1000 words etc and is so much easier for diagnosis.

Comment: How much water you give a plant depends upon the size (and season), hence why a photograph would be helpful, ideally 2, a close up of the markings and one of the entire pot and substrate. How long has this plant been in your family and has it been in the same spot for the entirety of it being with you?